# Can not get correct source tar.gz in copr.fedorainfracloud.org

Tags: rpmbuild

I try build wal-g into rpm on copr.fedorainfracloud.org

Github repo https://github.com/patsevanton/wal-g-rpm

Project https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/antonpatsev/wal-g/

Log https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/antonpatsev/wal-g/epel-7-x86_64/00891051-wal-g/builder-live.log

Size wal-g-0.2.7-1.src.rpm

```
wal-g-0.2.7-1.src.rpm   2019-Apr-27 12:04:19    7.54K   RPM File
```

Log:

```
+ /usr/bin/tar -xf -
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /builddir/build/SOURCES/wal-g.linux-amd64.tar.gz
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ /usr/bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
+ exit 0
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.Vdxk7R
+ umask 022
+ cd /builddir/build/BUILD
+ '[' /builddir/build/BUILDROOT/wal-g-0.2.7-1.x86_64 '!=' / ']'
+ rm -rf /builddir/build/BUILDROOT/wal-g-0.2.7-1.x86_64
++ dirname /builddir/build/BUILDROOT/wal-g-0.2.7-1.x86_64
+ mkdir -p /builddir/build/BUILDROOT
+ mkdir /builddir/build/BUILDROOT/wal-g-0.2.7-1.x86_64
+ cd wal-g-0.2.7
+ tree
.
`-- wal-g-0.2.7
    |-- LICENSE
    |-- README.md
    |-- build.sh
    |-- server-s3.conf
    |-- wal-g-rpm.spec
    `-- wal-g-rpm.spec-backup

1 directory, 6 files
+ /usr/bin/install -m 0755 -d /builddir/build/BUILDROOT/wal-g-0.2.7-1.x86_64/usr/local/bin
+ tree /builddir/build/SOURCES
/builddir/build/SOURCES
`-- wal-g.linux-amd64.tar.gz

0 directories, 1 file
+ ls -lh /builddir/build/SOURCES
total 8.0K
-rw-rw-r--. 1 mockbuild mock 5.4K Apr 27 12:14 wal-g.linux-amd64.tar.gz
+ cp wal-g /builddir/build/BUILDROOT/wal-g-0.2.7-1.x86_64/usr/local/bin/wal-g
cp: cannot stat 'wal-g': No such file or directory
```

How pack binary file from wal-g.linux-amd64.tar.gz to rpm ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only binary file, try to:

```
%prep
tar zxvf  %{_sourcedir}/wal-g.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```